# How can I install a CSC code which are not listed on Samsung Galaxy S/S2/S3 CSC app?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, csc

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2.

I want to change its CSC to any Indian version. I came to know that ODD, INU, IND, INA, INS, IMS & REL are the Indian CSCs. But when I checked it with [Samsung Galaxy S / S2/ S3 CSC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manniakk.cscselector), these CSCs are not listed.

How can I install a CSC which is not in the list?

Comment: You will have to use Odin to do the deed in performing a wipe/flash with the appropriate CSC, as @geffchang mentioned in his answer - you **will** lose everything on your handset so backup first before proceeding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change CSC, you need to wipe / Factory Reset your phone.

So, you might as well download and flash a stock ROM that is for India. It has Indian CSC.

**EDIT #1:** You do not need root to flash stock ROM on your phone using Odin.